# I am trying to post a value from a form which are in dynamic for loop. Every time I try it only post one value the first one

Tags: jquery

I tried both with id and class both gives me first value. I also tried with latest J query using "delegated" and "on"`enter code here` same result. I want to post the value I click on.

```
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.filecell').live('click',function() {  
        var $buttonData = $('input#hidden2').val();
           $.post('https://../servlet/AppQueOpenPDF'{FormName:$buttonData},function(data) {    
    $('#RepResponse3').html(data);

            });

        });

    });          

</script>
<TR>
   <TD CLASS='filecell'><input type='button' id='StatusAll' name ='StatusAll' value='HIST62083'></td>
    <TD CLASS='filecell'><input type='button' id='StatusAll' name ='StatusAll' value='HIST62282'></td>
<TR>
```

Comment: Where is `hidden2`   ???? Html rule violation don't use duplicate id. Live is depreciated  .

Answer (score 0):

Html rule violation don't use duplicate `id`. Live is depreciated . I think you want `button` value inside `td`. Use $`this` and `find` for this purpose.

```js
 $('.filecell').on('click', function() {
   var $buttonData = $(this).find('input:button').val();
   alert($buttonData);
   //other code goes here

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <TR>
    <TD CLASS='filecell'>
      <input type='button' id='StatusAll1' name='StatusAll' value='HIST62083'>
    </td>
    <TD CLASS='filecell'>
      <input type='button' id='StatusAll2' name='StatusAll' value='HIST62282'>
    </td>
    <TR>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I think I found the solution.

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[id^="tag"]').on('click', function() { 

            var $buttonData = this.value;
               $.post('https://172.16.101.120/servlet/AppQueOpenPDF',{FormName:$buttonData},function(data) {   

        $('#RepResponse3').html(data);

                });

            });

        });          

    </script>

    <td><input type='button' id='tag<%=count++%>'  name ='StatusAll' value='HIST62083'></td>
```